# How to replace URL in globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is working fine for first occurrence but i have multiple matched URL  occurrence  is not replacing.

If i am using global tag '**g**' first occurrence also not working.

I need to change all the matched URL.

**HTML:**

```
 <p id="demo">
    Welcome to <a href="http://google.com?sdfsdf">US </a> and s sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf<a href="http://google.com?sdfsdf">US </a>dfsdfsdfsd<a href="http://google.com?sdfsdf">US </a>sfsdfsdfsdfsdf<a href="http://live.com?dfgdfgdfg?dfgdfg=2016">US </a>
    </p>
```

**JS:**

```
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("http://google.com?sdfsdf", "sample link url");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

Comment: do you actually only want to replace the anchor `href` values, or also if the text appears visibly?

Comment: @haxxxton : only href value globally

Comment: @CodeMan I have changed my answer. I have now completely checked it and its working now. included the link to js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [jQuery attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to select all links that contain the href value you're looking for

```
var searchString = 'http://google.com?sdfsdf'; // specify the search value
var replaceString = 'Replace with me'; // specify the value to replace found strings with
// for each anchor tag with an href containing the search string
$("a[href*='" + searchString + "']").each(function(){
    // replace its current href with a the search string replaced
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(searchString, replaceString));
});
```

*NB: If you are actually attempting to replace the entire url of the matched elements, you can eliminate the need for the `.replace` function, like so:*

```
$(this).attr('href', replaceString);
```

Comment: You could probably get away without needing to use the replace function on the href string. By that time you know the searchString matches. `$(this).attr('href', replaceString);`

Comment: @synthet1c, you are correct, if we assumes that OP doesnt want to replace only part of the url, as it wasnt made clear in the question, i err'ed on the side of caution. I will add a note though

Answer (score 0):

check this. this might work https://jsfiddle.net/sfhmvrdo/

```
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://google.com">more google</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">fb</a>
<button>
click here
</button>
```

this is the jquery you need.

```
$('button').click(function(){

 change_href();
});

function change_href(){
 $("a").each(function() {
 if($(this).attr('href')=="http://google.com"){
 $(this).attr('href','http://facebook.com');
 }
 });
}
```